# How to send bulk emails I know to be unsolicited, with PHP?

Tags: php, email

I have a bit of an issue. How could I send over 200,000 emails? A customer of the company that I work for bought a list of emails close to 200,000. My boss wants me to send those emails no matter what.

We normally use Campaign Monitor or Mailchimp, but they will never allow us to send those emails. I already explained to my supervisor that there will be a problem, but he does not care, he wants those emails sent.

How could I possibly send all of those emails? Is there a service out there that will let me send them without checking the list? Or is there a platform to do just that?

I know that the mail function of PHP is not meant to send bulk email.

Comment: I would recommend looking into a *cloud mail service* with the appropriate service TOS/contract/quotas for that much email to said addresses. Failing that, a correctly setup mail-relay or queue (which is a server management role) would be a start ..

Comment: send them, get black listed, and we will all thank you for eliminating yourself from sending spam ever again or until you get a new IP block and domain

Comment: while i would normally love to help a spammer .. oh wait no.

Comment: Mail them. The post office doesn't care if you are spamming the snot out of people as long as you pay for each stamp.

Comment: Downvoting. If your customer has bought a list of emails, they are a potential spammer, and you should not be helping them. It's as simple as that, really.

Answer (score -1):

Technically php has no problem sending tons of emails e.g. Using mail function in a loop. However you have to know that if you use shared hosting then usually there is limited amount of emails that can be sent - 200-500 emails usually.

Comment: For large numbers of emails, `mail` is not a good way to go about it - personally I wouldn't use it at all. There are several libraries written for PHP that are much better at sending email.